# interface for fortran 77 in 95 program

Tags: fortran, implementation, fortran77, fortran95

I am quite new to fortran, and only write in fortran 95 and 2003. Now I have a program that is mainly written in 95, but it is completely in fortran 77 syntax and also contains some 77 functins.

Now I need the functionality in another program, but don't want to rewrite the whole program. My idea was to replace

```
program my_prog
```

with

```
module my_mod
subroutine my_prog()
```

The replacement does not seem to work. The compiler states, that the syntax from

```
subroutine my_prog()
```

is wrong. Does anyone have some experiance with the topic, or knows if it is even possible to implement the code without rewriting it?

Comment: when you say interface are you expecting to exchange information with the former program you converted to a subroutine?  Simply labeling it subroutine() w/  no arguments is likely not accomplishing what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for a module subroutine sub is

```
module name_of_the_module

  use whatever

  implicit none

  !some variables and interfaces

  contains

    subroutine sub
      !here is the code of your subroutine
    end subroutine sub

end module name_of_the_module
```

Otherwise, it should be noted, that you can call the code in FORTRAN 77 from a newer code. It is (with some exceptions) still a valid Fortran 2008 code, just in an old style. The only exception is you cannot mix free and fixed source format in one source file. That may also be your problem.

The best thing to do is to make the old functions and subroutines to conform also to the free source format (see "intersection format" [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Continuation+lines)) and place them into a module as I showed above.

Comment: cant say i agree with converting working fixed format code just for the fun of it.  Unless you want to paste it in the same file with free form code converting is unnecessary work and could introduce errors.

Comment: I do not see any potential for errors, as it can and should be done automatically. But the point of the answer is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Merely packaging a subroutine into a module may work in some cases but it may not work in others.
There are some features of Fortran 77 that have been declared obsolete now.   You have several options.

1. **Compiler switches:**   Many compilers provide compile time switches to compile legacy code. This depends on compiler to compiler and may change in the future
2. **Use tools:**   There are tools that people have written that allow you to convert f77 code into f90/95. For this see: 
   http://www.atmos.illinois.edu/courses/atms391-sp11/Fortran-converters.html
3. **Update source manually:**    Some people have used floating point variables in do-loops. This may be hard using automatic tools discussed above. In such cases where legacy statements like (goto) are present you may have to work manually. For this see the following link:

http://www.cisl.ucar.edu/zine/96/fall/articles/3.f90.conversion.html

http://iprc.soest.hawaii.edu/users/furue/improve-fortran.html

In the long run it will pay that you go through the code manually line-by-line and make the changes yourself. This is the most portable solution.

Comment: You are offering what exactly the OP wanted to avoid. Changing all the legacy code.